# Difference between numpy and tensorflow implementations of a simple logistic regression using stochastic gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to implement the Tensorflow code of a single logisitic regression neuron to classify a given digit as '7' or 'not 7'. I have previously done it with numpy and it works the way I expected it to. However, with Tensorflow it doesn't. I admit that there are more than a couple of things to make learning faster (Xavier initialization, batch learning, Adam optimization, randomized sample presentation, etc) but that is secondary. Right now my only concern is why I am unable to replicate my results with Tensorflow. Whether I am grossly misunderstanding some fundamental way that Tensorflow programs are written. I am an absolute beginner to Tensorflow, this is my first project.

These are the function definitions of the model implemented with numpy,

```
def Activation(z):
    """
    Returns the result of sigmoid function.
    """
    yPred = np.zeros(z.shape)
    for idx, val in enumerate(z):
        if(val >= 0):
            yPred[idx] = 1/(1+np.exp(-1*val))
        else:
            yPred[idx] = np.exp(val)/(1+np.exp(val))
    return yPred

def Predict(x, w, b):
    """
    Returns ypred = activation(W^T.X+b)
    """
    z = np.dot(w.T,x) + b
    yPred = Activation(z.reshape([-1, 1]));
    return yPred

def ComputeLoss(yPred, y):
    """
    Cross entropy loss
    """
    # 'epsilon' prevents log domain error                                                                         
    epsilon = 1e-8                                                             
    return -1*(y*np.log(yPred+epsilon)+(1-y)*np.log((1-yPred)+epsilon))

def UpdateParameters(w, b, error, x, eta):
    """
    Learning rule / Backprop
    """
    dw = x.dot(error);
    w -= eta*dw;
    b -= eta*error 
    return w, b
```

To make sure that the numpy and Tensorflow are initiaited with identical weights, I am using the `tf.initializers.constant` initializer. I sift through the data to seperate the MNIST dataset into two classes with '7' and ones without '7'. I am not including the code I have used to do that here (to keep the relevant code brief). I have posted it as a part of a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179358/variables-not-updated-after-training-in-tensorflow-even-when-initiated-with-unif). The training part of the program is,

```
# Numpy weights and bias initialization
InputSize = 784
w = np.random.rand(InputSize);
w = w.reshape([w.shape[0],1]);
b = np.random.rand();

MaxEpochs = 1
eta = 2e-5
ValidationInterval = 1

# Building TF graph
ops.reset_default_graph()
n_x = InputSize
n_y = 1

x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [n_x, None], name = 'x_tf')
y_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [n_y, None], name = 'y_tf')    

w_tf = tf.get_variable(name = "w_tf", shape = [n_x, 1], initializer = tf.initializers.constant(w));
b_tf = tf.get_variable(name = "b_tf", shape = [n_y, 1], initializer = tf.initializers.constant(b));

yPred_tf = tf.add(tf.matmul(w_tf, x_tf, transpose_a = True), b_tf, name = 'yPred_tf')

Loss_tf = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = yPred_tf, labels = y_tf, name = 'Loss_tf')
with tf.name_scope('Training'):
    optimizer_tf = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = eta)
    train_step = optimizer_tf.minimize(Loss_tf)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()                                                        # to initialize weights and bias

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for Epoch in range(MaxEpochs):
        for Sample in range(len(XTrain)):
            # Numpy learning
            yPred = Predict(XTrain[Sample], w, b)
            Loss = ComputeLoss(yPred, YTrain[Sample])
            w, b = UpdateParameters(w, b, yPred - YTrain[Sample], XTrain[Sample], eta)
            # Tensorflow learning
            x = XTrain[Sample]
            y = YTrain[Sample].reshape([-1,1])
            Train_sample = {x_tf: x, y_tf: y}
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = Train_sample)

        if((Epoch+1) %ValidationInterval == 0):
            # Numpy validation
            YPredTest = Predict(XTest, w, b);
            YPredTest = YPredTest.reshape([len(YTest),1])
            TestSetError = np.sum(np.abs(YTest-YPredTest))
            print('Validation Error of the NP model at', Epoch+1,'Epoch:', int(TestSetError))
            # Tensorflow validation
            x = XTest.reshape([n_x, -1])
            y = YTest.reshape([1,-1])
            Test = {x_tf: x, y_tf: y}
            yPred = sess.run(tf.sigmoid(yPred_tf), feed_dict = Test)
            ValidationError = np.sum(np.abs(yPred - y))
            print('Validation Error of the TF model at', Epoch+1,'Epoch:', int(ValidationError))
```

At the end of it the numpy implementation reaches a validation set error of 255 whereas the Tensorflow implementation is at 8972 (over different runs, so still baseline guess).

The weights are changing as per the following histogram summary:
[image]

Thank you for your input.

Comment: If this really the right way to compute errors? Shouldn't you clip the network outputs to `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: Hmm... Ya. I think I should do clip them to zero or one. But I still don't understand why there is such a big difference in the values. The reason why I didn't clip it is because tee sigmoid returns values close to 0 or 1 for most values anyway.